# Finding the velocity of an object from its horizontal and vertical components?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Let's say a ball is thrown and it experiences typical projectile motion (moves in a parabolic arc etc.) and the only information we know are the equations for the horizontal and vertical components of its velocity for it's entire path.

From the given information, how does one calculate the total/actual velocity of the ball relative to the direction it is travelling in at any given point (ignoring drag)?

As an example (horizontal and vertical components of velocity respectively):

$V_x = 30$

$V_y = 20 - 9.81t$

Is it simply a matter of using Pythagoras and taking the magnitude?

$ V=\sqrt{(V_x)^2 + (V_y)^2} $

Comment: Technically this is the speed, but yes, this is what you are looking for.

Comment: A little more trig to find the angle and you have yourself the velocity

Comment: $V=V_x \hat i + V_y \hat j$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the advice given in the comments, the magnitude of the net velocity is as you wrote it out. It'll be a function of $t$ as expected.

As for the direction, note that a little triangle is made if you draw out the velocity vector with its components. The angle $\theta$ with respect to the horizon has $$\tan  \theta = \frac{V_y}{V_x} \implies \theta = \arctan \frac{V_y}{V_x}=\arctan \frac{20-9.81t}{30}$$ In this formula, the angle you will get will be positive until $V_y=0$ at which point it will be zero (because the body moves horizontally momentarily) and after that point you will have negative angles which would signify the angle *below* the horizon.